# Two CSS bodies inside one Html page

Tags: html, css, ejs

I am trying to figure out how can I use two bodies inside an HTML page without. In case it is not possible what other options do I have?

header.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
.
.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/Nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/logoLed.css">

</head>
<body>
```

navbar.ejs

```
.
.
  <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/events">Home</a>
        </li>
      
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/shops/productsView">SHOP</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
.
.
```

ledLogo.ejs

```
    <div class="box">
            <span class="glass"></span>
                    <div class="hexagonMain" style="background-color:DodgerBlue;" >
                        <div class="rowHexagon" >
                            <div class="hexagon"></div>
.
.
```

logoLed.css

```
.
.
body{
    display:  flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #010615;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.
.
```

Nav.css

```
.
.
      body
        {
            float: right;
            justify-content: right;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 30vh;
            background: #000;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
.
.
```

So basically, navbar.ejs needs the body from Nav.css and ledLogo.ejs needs the body from logoLed.css , and I need to use navbar.ejs and  ledLogo.ejs on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

The browser doesn't care *how* the HTML document it gets is generated, so the fact you are using EJS is largely irrelevant.

The browser gets one HTML document with one BODY element. (You might have multiple `<body>` tags, but you shouldn't, and error recovery rules will cause them to be combined / discarded until you have one).

---

Your CSS can have any many rulesets with the selector `body` as you like. They will all be applied, in order (see [The Cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) for mode details).

If you want to target two different elements, than they can't both target the `<body>`. You need to change at least one of them to target a different element (such as a `<div>` or the `<main>` element). You might need to create a new element to target.